# Does Shi'is believe Ali can't forget?

Tags: shiism, ali

Question for Shi'i Muslims: Can Ali (RA) forget (anything) according to Shi'i fiqh (authentic citations/references such as hadith/fiqhi opinions preferred rather than a straight answer)?

Answer (score 0):

The Shiite Imams are twelve members of the Ahl al-Bayt of the Prophet (PBUH) who, according to the narrations, are the successors of the Prophet and after him the Imam of the Islamic society. The first Imam is Hazrat Ali (AS) and the other Imams are his children and grandchildren and Hazrat Zahra (AS).
According to the Imami Shiites, the Imams (AS) have been appointed to the Imamate by God and have characteristics such as infallibility, superiority, knowledge of the unseen and the right of intercession. According to the definition of the infallibility of the Imams, the purity of the Shiite Imams is from any major or minor sin, intentional and inadvertent mistake, as well as forgetfulness. Because forgetfulness is a kind of memory impairment and disability.

Shiite scholars have cited several verses to prove the infallibility of the Imams, such as the first verse, the verse of purification and the verse of Ibrahim's affliction, the verse of the truthful, the verse of Mawdat, and the verse of Salawat. In narration sources, many narrations have been narrated in this regard. The hadith of Saqaleen, the hadith of Aman and the hadith of Safina are among the narrations that have been cited to prove the infallibility of the Imams (A.S.). Despite numerous reasons for the infallibility of the Imams, the Wahhabis and Ibn Taymiyyah al-Harrani, the leader of the Salafis, have denied it and made objections to it. Shiite scholars have answered all the problems.
But all this is to prove that Imam Ali (a.s.) and other Imams do not inherently suffer from defects and disorders of forgetfulness. That is, since they are in a high position like the rulers of Muslims, they always benefit from consciousness, and the light of their consciousness is never dimmed or dimmed. This is far from the concept of "can not forget."

https://fa.wikishia.net/view/%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86_%D8%B4%DB%8C%D8%B9%D9%87

https://www.salamati24.com/fa/blog-post/8459/